# The ring S is integral domain or field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[i] := \{a + ib \in \mathbb{ C} : a, b \in  \mathbb{Z}\}$ be the ring of Gaussian integers. Let $I := (4 + 5i)$ be
>   the principal ideal generated by $4 + 5i$ and $S := \mathbb{Z}[i]/ I $
>   be the quotient ring. Then
>
> - $S$ is an integral domain.
> - $S$ is not an integral domain.
> - $S$  is a field.
> - $S$ is  an integral domain but not a field

I  think this will be integral  domain  because $\Bbb{Z}$ is integral domain but not field.

Any hints/ solution

Thanks u

Comment: $\Bbb Z[i]/(4+5i)\cong \Bbb Z / 41 \Bbb Z$, so $S$ is a field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$4+5i$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, since $\vert \vert 4+5i \vert \vert=4^2+5^2=41$, a prime number

So $\langle 4+5i \rangle$ is maximal and $R/I$ is a field as well as an integral domain